# Image is not shown on php when I call mysql blob

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I'm trying to get an image loaded on a mysql database as a blob. When I try to load, it just appear a black screen with a square in the middle. Like the image I attach.

please your help

PHP (file who show the image)

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
require_once('sql.php');
require_once('encriptor.php');

$usrId = $_SESSION['usr-id'];
$sec= new encryptor();

$usrId = $sec->decrypt($usrId);

$db = new sql();

$consulta="CALL sp_getUserProfileImage(".$usrId.")";
$img="";
foreach($db->retorna($consulta) as $a)
{
    $img=$a->picture;
}

echo $img;
?>
```

this is the line where I call the image:

```
<img src="masterlib/php/image_show.php" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
```

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KwDK.jpg)

please your help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Image in website need to have a directory like `c:\images\sample.jpeg`

You `can't do it` by fetching a blob from `DB` and assign the `blob` to an `image control`

**Moving forward:**

Save your image first then get the image file from your directory.